# Why code runner extension taking too much time to execute?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have made a very simple program to test the VS code Runner extension.
My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter two numbers to add\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    c = a + b;

    printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

After running the code and waiting for many minutes it still shows

```
 [Running] cd "/home/souro/Desktop/" && gcc souro.c -o souro && "/home/souro/Desktop/"souro
```

No output is showing it only shows running.

Comment: there's probably an interactive console somewhere. Find it.

Comment: Did you manage to enter the input?

Comment: No there is no place to enter input it only shows running and there is no interactive console @ leyanpan.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the terminal for running the code, if you're currently using the output window then it might not be working.
Go to settings, in the search bar type 'terminal' and look for' code runner:run in terminal ' make sure to check the box and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings search for Code-runner: run in terminal
enable it

Comment: This have been already proposed [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257115/10952503) and it seems wrong according to the score

Answer (score -1):

Go to VSCode settings and search for 'terminal', then scroll to find 'Code-runner: run in terminal' and enable it.

Answer (score -3):

Check your IntelliSense settings, set the compiler path and IntelliSense mode to g++ and gccx-64 (if you are using C and C++ in windows). Reinstall the extension and create a new file of .c or .cpp and then try again.
After that make sure you run your output through terminal, which you can set as follows- Go to settings>extensions>C/C++>Run code configuration>Scroll down and then check the box which says run in terminal.